# Order of an element given a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> If  $G_1,G_2$ are groups, $\varphi:G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ is a homomorphism and $a \in(G_1)$, is an element of finite order, what can we say for the order $\varphi(a)$?

My attempt so far:
Let $\operatorname{ord}(a)=r$; Then $(a^r)=e_1 $. But can I use this  to claim that: ($\varphi(a)^r$)$=e_2$?

Comment: Yes, because $\varphi(a^r)=\bigl(\varphi(a)\bigr)^r$.

Comment: But why this is true?

Comment: By a nursery school induction on the definition of a group homomorphism.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can claim that because $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, hence $e_2=\varphi(a^r)=(\varphi(a))^r$ and then you can deduce that the order of $\varphi(a)$ divides $r$.